# Middleware seems to be overlooked by the server

Tags: node.js, express

In this example I made a middleware that supposed to log `req.path` on root. This function seems to be completely overlooked by the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static("./public"));

app.use('/', function(req, res, next){ // the functions
    console.log("req.path = ", req.path); // no console entries on request
    next();
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I also tried to put both `express.static()` and the function together as arguments of `app.use` but still to no effect:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/', 
express.static("./public"),
function(req, res, next){
    console.log("req.path = ", req.path);
    next();
});

function foo(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.path);
    next();
}

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

What am I not getting right?

EDIT: if I put my middleware before `express.static` it works as intended. What appears to be the problem?

Comment: If your `public` directory has an `index.html` file, then the next route will never be reached.

Comment: @OrelEraki It works now. Console result: req.path =  / req.path =  /styles.css
req.path =  /database.js
req.path =  /scripts.js What appears to be the problem? Doesn't `express.static` have `next()`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is `index.html` a special name in regard of serving files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
app.use('/', express.static("./public"));
```

There are two things that is happening.

**1)** `.use` is basically used to add middlewares to all the request matching the path. Or if the path is not specified, it will be used for ALL the routes.
**FYI:** request goes through all the middlware by the position of their declaration. For ex:

```
app.use(mid1);
app.use(mid2);
```

means a request will go through **mid1** then **mid2** then the route **handler**.

**2)** By `.use`ing `static` with `/` means that every route `/*` will be going through the `express.static` middleware and try to find the file in your `public` folder. If it is not found you will get a 404 and will not go to the next middleware. If it is found then it will pipe the file using `stream.pipe(res)`

So by using the `express.static` after your middleware, you are saying first go through my middleware then search in `./public` folder.

What you can do is push up your middlware and use a specific route for the static middleware.

Comment: So After `express.static` uses `stream.pipe` all middleware processing is over? What if I want to use some middleware after that, for example to check the result of the request or log some info?